# Vertically concatenating multiple data frames within a loop in R

Tags: r

I have 40 data frames (same size) let's say station_1, station_2,....,station_40

In each loop there will be different stations that need to be vertically concatenated. For example, in a particular loop, i want to concatenate [station_2, station_3, station_11, station_30, station_40]. How can i code the R to do that without explicitly specifying the names of those station?

Comment: Are you looking for a `cbind` function perhaps?

Comment: Please, provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask] and [mcve] before posting your next question.

Answer (score 0):

We can get the datasets in a `list` using `mget` and then `rbind` them (assuming vertically concatenated implies that) with `do.call`

```
res <- do.call(rbind, mget(paste0("station_", c(2, 3, 11, 30, 40))))
```

NOTE: Here we assume that the dataset objects have the same column names